# Get sites from which user is member of user's My Site

Tags: user-profile, my-site, membership

One of the requirements of our SharePoint installation is that in each user's My Site-Profile, we need to show what pages he is a member of - separated by site categories (projects, etc.)

In other words, I'd like to have a feature similar to the Memberships page but only for certain sites (projects and another kind of site) and somewhat separated.

Where should I begin ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

for getting list of sites user has access to , I would check this project out and then get the code I want as in this project they are showing all the sites user has access to.

[SharePoint Sushi](http://sushi.codeplex.com)

Its more like reverse engineering but if you a bit of C# you can do it

[Source Code](http://sushi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)

unless you want Powershell script you can check this [Check Sites User got permission of](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2010/04/discovering-who-has-access-to-sharepoint-2010-securable-objects/) out